# Как достать данные с определенным именем из массива данных JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net, frontend

Отправил в представление следующий лист объектов:

```
List<Worker> workers;

public class Worker
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
    List<Child> Childs {get;set;}
}

public class Child 
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

На стороне клиента преобразовал в JSON и теперь не могу достать массив из имен работников. B JS есть что-либо вроде LINQ, как в C# или придется пробегать циклом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let result = array.map(x => x.FullName);
```